# DNS not functioning on command line

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, dns, vagrant

I recently did a combination of Vagrant + VirtualBox stuff on my machine to try to get a virtualized Ubuntu install working. However, I had no luck with it so I just uninstalled everything. Ever since then, I've had some issues with using command line applications on my host machine.

I'm on Windows 7 x64. DNS resolution and network connectivity seem to be fine through Chrome browser and other GUI based tools. However, when I launch cmd.exe, I notice weird behavior out of various command line tools.

## nslookup

Executing `nslookup` results in inability to find IP address of basic domain names.

```
C:\>nslookup google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.3.1.1

*** UnKnown can't find google.com: No response from server
```

`10.3.1.1` is my router, which supplies itself as the DNS server to clients via DHCP. The router forwards DNS requests to the Google DNS servers. As I said, DNS resolution is working in my browser and through many other applications so I doubt my router setup or DNS servers are the issue. I will leave out those details here to keep the topic simple.

## ping

`ping` works for physical IPv4 addresses but not for hostnames.

```
C:\>ping google.com
Ping request could not find host google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

```
C:\>ping 8.8.8.8
Pinging  with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=52
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=52

Ping statistics for _`&:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 30ms, Average = 29ms
```

## netstat

Now here's where it gets interesting. When I run the `netstat` command, the `Local Address` field is empty, although IPv6 addresses still show up. It's just the IPv4 ones that do not. This was working fine before!

```
C:\>netstat -ano

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       544
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       904
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       616
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4556
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       6756
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       1080
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       3612
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       3436
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       3436
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     4
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     5196
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     1444
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     3436
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  CLOSE_WAIT      3612
  TCP                                                  CLOSE_WAIT      3612
  TCP                                                  CLOSE_WAIT      3612
  TCP                                                  CLOSE_WAIT      3612
  TCP                                                  CLOSE_WAIT      3612
  TCP                                                  CLOSE_WAIT      3612
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     3612
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     2944
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       3320
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4576
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       5196
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     4556
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     4556
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     6756
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     6756
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     3612
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     3612
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     3612
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       3612
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       3612
  TCP                                                  ESTABLISHED     3612
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       2960
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       2044
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       1420
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4
  TCP                                                  LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:1025              [::]:0                 LISTENING       544
  TCP    [::]:1026              [::]:0                 LISTENING       904
  TCP    [::]:1038              [::]:0                 LISTENING       616
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1080
  TCP    [::]:3587              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5700
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:32400             [::]:0                 LISTENING       3436
  TCP    [::]:32401             [::]:0                 LISTENING       3436
  TCP    [::1]:1028             [::]:0                 LISTENING       1768
  UDP                           *:*                                    1000
  UDP                           *:*                                    964
  UDP                           *:*                                    964
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    1000
  UDP                           *:*                                    1080
  UDP                           *:*                                    3612
  UDP                           *:*                                    3172
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3172
  UDP                           *:*                                    2944
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    2944
  UDP                           *:*                                    2944
  UDP                           *:*                                    964
  UDP                           *:*                                    4
  UDP                           *:*                                    4
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    2960
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    1420
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    4
  UDP                           *:*                                    4
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    4
  UDP                           *:*                                    4
  UDP                           *:*                                    1568
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP                           *:*                                    3436
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*                                    1000
  UDP    [::]:3540              *:*                                    5700
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    964
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    964
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*                                    1000
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                                    1080
  UDP    [::]:58964             *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [::]:64135             *:*                                    964
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [::1]:64131            *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [fe80::2923:9898:cce9:9b60%18]:1900  *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [fe80::41ba:5355:289f:f5fa%27]:1900  *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [fe80::8c37:8952:a3d5:ca0%20]:1900  *:*                                    1568
  UDP    [fe80::8c37:8952:a3d5:ca0%20]:64130  *:*                                    1568
```

Things I have done to try to remedy the issue:

- Reboots
- Uninstall NIC drivers; reinstall from motherboard manufacturer
- `ipconfig /flushdns`
- `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Asked it nicely

None of these worked. Anyone know what the issue is or steps I can take to diagnose it?

## Vagrant / VirtualBox Details

I want this at the bottom because it's quite lengthy and potentially irrelevant. However, I want to discuss it because this is what I believe triggered this issue.

I ran a series of Vagrant commands to install Ubuntu Trusty 32 on Virtual Box:

```
$ vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64
$ vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
$ vagrant up
```

However, it had issues with DNS resolution in the guest OS. So I set a few flags on my VM to get it working:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Ubuntu Trusty 64" --natdnshostresolver1 on
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Ubuntu Trusty 64" --natdnsproxy1 on
```

While this did resolve the DNS resolutions on Ubuntu guest OS, port forwarding still didn't work. So because it wasn't working I gave up completely and uninstalled Vagrant and VirtualBox after deleting the virtual machines it installed/setup. After this is when I noticed that command line stuff and even commands run though msys weren't working anymore. DNS resolution issues now exist in my host OS!

## EDIT

I will amend my question with requests from comments below.

Settings under adapter IPv4:
[image: IPv4 settings]

All available adapters on my system are below, per `ipconfig /all` command (The adapter named `Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection` is my real physical network adapter connected to the LAN).

Also note I changed my DNS servers to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` respectively. Normally my gateway is my DNS server (`10.3.1.1`). I did this to rule out any issues with my router and per someone's suggestion in the comments.

```
C:\>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Robert-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 90-2B-34-57-0D-24
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8c37:8952:a3d5:ca0%20(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.38(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, May 25, 2015 9:35:57 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, May 26, 2015 9:36:00 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-05-9A-3C-78-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2923:9898:cce9:9b60%18(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.155.96(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 654312858
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-03-8A-D9-90-2B-34-57-0D-24
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Reusable ISATAP Interface {D85DF6F3-7D47-4198-B7B9-DD5680A8A6E7}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

With my DNS manually set to Google's DNS servers, I ran `nslookup` (output below). Note that I am still not able to resolve hostnames using `nslookup` or `ping` after the DNS change to Google DNS servers.

```
C:\>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8
```

Comment: When you go to your network adapter on the windows7  machine, what are the settings under ipv4?

Comment: So that typically happens when there is no reverse dns record/zone available. Try setting 'use the following DNS server addresses' to 8.8.8.8 or another public DNS IP. See if that works and, if so, try switching it to your router's IP. If that fails see if there are some additional settings to change in the router - perhaps provide your routers model etc.

Comment: @Abraxas I set Preferred and Alternate IP addresses to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` respectively. `ping google.com` still doesn't work. I saved the settings and disabled/reenabled the adapter. Still nothing!

Comment: What happens when you just type nslookup without another argument?

Comment: It enters interactive mode.

Comment: Above that does it give a default server? Typically you'll see: Default Server and Address above that prompt - I expect this will say Unknown and your router IP. My suspicion is that you can set different default DNS servers in your router (perhaps use this to identify the best ones https://code.google.com/p/namebench/ ) and this will fix your issue.

Comment: It says unknown and then 8.8.8.8 below that. I don't see how this can be my router, it hasn't changed. And steam and chrome work just fine.

Comment: I updated my post to include the results of `ipconfig /all` and also `nslookup` after DNS servers have been manually set in adapter settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much investigation, I came across these threads:

- http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/286086-unable-run-ping-traceroute-2.html
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-network-adapter-error-some-controls-on/580b87fd-d722-49ae-9520-092c73149854?msgId=28c7bac1-c3a9-4cb6-b3a4-ed7cb7a725c0

The solution was to run these commands:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

Answer (score -1):

If there was no reverse dns zone, then DNS would still work.  Please stop answering all these posts with that.  Everywhere everyone says the same thing, and every user with this problem, repsonds.  No That is not it.  They even state in most of the threads that servers on the same subnet/vrf/vlan all work fine, pointing to the same DNS server, which is a DC, which has a REVERSE zone.  When there is no reverse zone, DNS still responds, just non-authoritative.  In this case DNS does not respond.  Ping via name doesn't respond.  But going to explorer and doing \host works.  Someone has to have seen and solved this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You've got a bit of a rant going on here.  The answer seems more focused on critiquing something else than providing a solution.  If there is an actual solution here, it gets lost.  Can you whittle this down to focus just on the solution?  If you feel the need to supplement that with commentary, you can do that in a comment on your answer.  Thanks.